# Efficiently search/grep in file

Tags: search, grep

I would like to replace records in file by order: Platinum lines; Gold lines; Silver lines; Bronze lines ; Rest

```
 yf=$(grep -i Platinum $fname)
 yf="$yf"$(grep -i Gold $fname)
 yf="$yf"$(grep -i Silver $fname)
 yf="$yf"$(grep -i Bronze $fname)   
 yf="$yf"$(grep -h -v -i Bronze $fname|grep -h -v -i Gold|grep -h -v -i Silver|grep -h -v -i Platinum  2>/dev/null)
```

Too much reads of the file.
I would like to make it more efficiently.  Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: On SO we encourage users to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly update your post with same.

Comment: You could use `mapfile` to load the file into a line-indexed bash array. The rest is fairly straightforward.